# How do I get string between multiple start words and multiple end words from strings using Python?

Tags: python, regex

I am having these string.

```
Top of Prod. Zone Dist: 170 feet Direction: FNL Dist: 596 feet Direction:
Top of Prod. Zone Distance: 528 ft Direction: FNL Distance: 114 ft Direction:    
Top of Prod. Zone Dist**. 170 ft Direction: FNL Dist**: 596 ft Direction:
Top of Prod. Zone Dist. Direction: FNL Dist: 596 Direction:
Top of Prod. Zone Dist. 78 Direction: FNL Dist: 596 Direction:
```

I want to get everything between "***Dist:***" or "***Distance:***" or "***Dist*****" or "***Dist.***" and "***feet***" or "***ft***" or "***Direction (if feet is not there)***"

I can use below regular expression if I have one start and one end word but in my case there are multiple start words and multiple end words.

```
re.findall('Dist:(.*?)feet', string, re.DOTALL)
```

Please help me to create a regular expression which I can use for multiple words.

Comment: Use `re.findall('Dist:(.*?)(?:feet|$)', string, re.DOTALL)`

Comment: @Wiktor it is good for multiple end words but how can add multiple start words as well in this expression ? Start words could be ***Dist:*** or ***Distance*** or ***Dist.***.

Comment: Well, same technique: `re.findall('Dist(?:[:.]|ance:)(.*?)(?:feet|$)', string, re.DOTALL)` or something. Do you have the "words" in some list variable?

Comment: @Wiktor I am sorry for not mentioning this in my question but start word could also be a ***Interval*** or ***Gap***.

Comment: So,put them into a non-capturing group. `r'(Dist:|word2|word3|etc\.)(.*?)(?:feet|more_here|$)'`

Comment: Thank you so much @Wiktor i am getting this output. ***[('Dist:', ' 170 '), ('Dist:', ' 596 ')]***. Is there a way I can get only ***[' 170 ', ' 596 ']*** ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167330/discussion-between-shadkhan-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: Use non-capturing group `(?:Dist:|word2|word3|etc\.)`, same as  at the end

Comment: Thank a lot @Wiktor Stribiżew.